# My script does not print out in browser

Tags: php

What is wrong with this simple php script? For some reason Hello World is not printed in my browser when i open the file. I have installed WAMP.

```
<html>
<head> <title> Hello World </title> </head>
<body>
<p>
<?php
// A first example
echo "Hello World";
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the filename end with .php?

Comment: Yes filename ends with .php and it opens with Firefox. Nothing is printed.

Comment: Click here http://localhost and tell us what you see

Comment: this is what i see http://postimage.org/image/21vk1mu6c/

Answer (score 2):

The Script is fine.
Check that:
1. WAMP is running.
2. You have saved the file with .php extension
3. Are you getting any errors. (to enable errors you may need to change the display_errors in php.ini file)

Answer (score 1):

might be there are some issues with you like

1. First check your wamp server running
2. check your file end with proper extension `filename.php`
3. Check your file is in right directory `www/filename.php`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have associated the .php files with php in your apache configuration (wamp\bin\apache\ApacheX.X.X\conf\httpd.conf) like this:

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: Doesn't WAMP do this when you run the setup/install it?

Comment: Yes, but you can mess this up afterwards. And in linux servers, this is one of the most obvious reasons that php is not executed

Comment: that is ok, it was by default so.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably accessing the file directly. You have to access it via browser-localhost and not directly.

WAMP has pretty much every set-up done.

Go to http://localhost/ on your browser, you should see the WAMP homepage. Save your scripts in the proper directory, i.e `c:/wamp/www/`

Comment: I added my script there but still same.

Comment: @MiyamotoMusashi Then it works. Save your script in `c:/wamp/www/` and visit it in the browser using `http://localhost/myscript.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your php script in `C:\wamp\www\test` (or whatever your wamp installation folder is).

Then refresh, and you should see `test` under `Your projects` in the welcome page you have.